# Need to convert VGA to DVI-D

Tags: display, vga, dvi, kvm-switch

In my server I have a VGA port but need to connect the port with a KVM switch that contains a DVI-D Port. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

**Server : HP DL180G9
KVM : MXT5110#DVI**

[image]

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Answer (score -1):

In order to properly convert the signal from an analog to a digital interface, you will need this box posted below. Any other attempts will be rendered futile, as it seems your KVM only has a digital input, and your server an analog one. 
http://www.ebay.com/itm/PC-VGA-to-DVI-D-Digital-Video-Format-Converter-/230616333659

Source: http://www.ambery.com/vgatodidvifo.html

Comment: It might be more accurate to say that an active converter is required, and that is an example of one.  The answer wording sort of implies that only that specific unit will do the job.